# Shorthand for \begin{eqnarray*} ... \end{eqnarray*}

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

To align a long string of symbols I usually use

```
\begin{eqnarray*} ... \end{eqnarray*}.
```

I would like to know if there is any convenient alternative to this environment. For example, I know that

```
\[ ... \]
```

can replace

```
$$ ... $$ and is more viable than

$$ ... $$.
```

What I am after is a simple alternative such that it is to

```
\begin{eqnarray*} ... \end{eqnarray*}
```

what

```
\[ ... \]
```

is to

```
$$ ... $$.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `\[`...`\]` is *not* a replacement or shorthand for `$$`...`$$`. It's preferred due to improved vertical spacing; see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764).

Also, [`eqnarray` does not provide the best horizontal spacing around operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

If shorthand is what you're after, then you could use `\be`...`\ee` as an alternative to `\begin{eqnarray*}`...`\end{eqnarray*}` where

```
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{eqnarray*}}
```

I would not recommend it though.

Perhaps you're stuck on the notation used by `eqnarray`:

```
... & .. & ... \\
... & .. & ...
```

In that sense, you may be interested in using the following alternative that combines the preferred notation `\[`...`\]` with the use of `eqnarray`'s double-`&`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\ba}{% "\begin{eqnarray*}"
  \[% Start display math
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764
    \begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}l@{}}% Start a 3-column array
}
\newcommand{\ea}{% "\end{eqnarray*}"
    \end{array}% End array
  \]% End display math
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
\end{align*}

\ba
  f(x) &=& ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &=& ax^2 + bx + c
\ea

\end{document}
```